# Parse Quick Start with YUN

Tags: parse-platform, arduino-yun

i'm tring to start with YUN and Parse with first example:

```
ParseObjectCreate create;
create.setClassName("TestObject");
create.add("foo", "bar");
ParseResponse response = create.send();
Serial.println("\nResponse for saving a TestObject:");
Serial.print(response.getJSONBody());
if (!response.getErrorCode()) {
  String objectId = response.getString("objectId");
  Serial.print("Test object id:");
  Serial.println(objectId);
} else {
  Serial.println("Failed to save the object");
}
response.close(); // Do not forget to free the resource
```

When i lauch RUN i obtain only:

Test object id:

without any other else.
What could be the problem?

Thanks

NR

Answer (score 0):

My experience was that I needed to run the "setup" Arduino sketch (just once) to get the Linux side properly configured.  After that I could run the sample scripts repeatedly with success.